# expected ; when parsing csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, csv

I'm trying to parse with javascript and [papaparse](http://papaparse.com). Problem is, that I'm getting an error that I don't understand. My csv delimiter is semicolon `;`, and that's fine, but for some reason, when parsing my csv I get an error saying:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Please check it out yourself at http://itpsychology.net/test/ and notice the error in your console.

Comment: Hazardous guess, it may have to do with all the ø, æ, å in your file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use    dataType: 'script'    . To load CSV file, use     dataType: 'text'    and parse it with your parse method.